# Book starts from left page

Tags: documentclass

I'm writing my thesis using the book document class in LaTeX.
I don't know why, but after the last compilation the document started from the left page. As you can see the right margin of the first page is wider, because that's where the binding would go.
[image]

The same thing happens with the first page of the table of contents, but I would like to start everything from the right page, with binding on the left side.
[image]

It is very strange, since the first line of code is:

```
\documentclass [10 pt , a4 paper , twoside, openright]{book}
```

Also if i set it to "openleft", nothing changes. Do you know which packages can interfere with document class? Thank you.

Comment: Usually, the wider margin is the outer margin, e.g. the left margin on a right (odd) page is wider than the left margin on a right page.

Comment: All the chapters start on odd (right)  pages (3, 5, 9, ) so they are OK. The page number of Indice should be i.  The problem is with the margin setup.

Comment: the right margin is larger for you thumbs, and to equalize the space so the two inner margins together are similar to the outer margin

Comment: note that the package options are `10pt` and `a4paper` with no space, the spaces are ignored more or less by accident